# Evaluation metrics of XAI techniques output

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, image-processing, metric, explanatory-models

Consider multiple videos with N frames. I have M models and X XAI methods. Basically, i've trained and evaluated some models (classification task, real/deepfake) on these N frames and I've obtained some results with different XAI methods. Now I would like to find like a 'metric of credibility' of the results that I got. It would be nice to have a sort of agreement between the components N,M and X. Is there any kind of metrics that could be useful in that sense?

Comment: Could you please explain your terms? XAI?

Comment: Explainable Artificial Intelligence (XAI). The methods that i've used are LIME and GradCAM